# Redux and react-navigation bottom-tabs component

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm currently working on an app on which I have integrated **Redux** and **react-navigation** and I can't figure out how to do this correctly :

I have to use a **bottom tabs** navigation bar that I got from *react-native-material-bottom-tabs* and right now, I have a connection view, and the view that render the navigation bar with the **redux router** to navigate between those two.

There is a profile view with some **children views** displayed in one of the Bottom bar navigation's view and I can't figure out **how to setup navigation** for those views because they are inside a Bottom Navigation class, which is in the current redux navigation, but not the views it contains...

I tried different things such as local navigator inside the profile view for  it and his children but I can't use my redux store by passing it to the local Navigator...

Right now architecture is ***AppNavigator*** contains { Connection , BottomTabs } and ***BottomTabs*** contains { Profile View, Home View, Event View }

How can I supply **navigation** and **store** with redux inside my bottom bar's view?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this 'react-native-tabbar-bottom' api from npm you can also refer following link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tabbar-bottom.

Comment: thanks, but I have to use the react-navigation module with react-navigation-material-bottoms-tabs in order to keep material design

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it don't seem right : I pass the informations through the *screenProps* props of a StackNavigation, and those informations comes from my redux store.

This solutions works while finding a better way to handle it.